# Best practice to store composite object in database

Tags: database, design-patterns

I have some hierarchy of objects in my program (i.e. PHP). Its composite design pattern used. I.e. `countries -> states -> cities -> districts`. Whithin my code I often work with this objects as some abstract area unit. Now, I should save all of this objects in database (i.e. MySQL).

What is best database structure for comfortable storing and getting back thus objects? Should I create different tables for each type of objects (`country_table, state_table, city_table ...`) or store all objects in one table areaUnit_table?

Comment: Take a look at this [awasome post][1] about this topic.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database